# Проблема с inline

Tags: c++, winapi, функции, inline

Здравствуйте! Пишу обработчик для `WM_MOUSEMOVE` для своего элемента UI. Есть массив этих элементов UI `Сol *col[100000]={NULL}`, часть которого не `NULL`. Так вот, если ниже приведённый код(обработчик) находиться непосредственно в `case WM_MOUSEMOVE:` то с производительностью всё нормально. Но если обернуть обработчик в функцию находящуюся в хидере, и в `MOUSEMOVE` просто вызывать её, то производительность значительно падает(лагает короче). Уже перепробовал и `inline` и `__forceinline inline`, ничего не помогает..

Тут можно что-то сделать?

Код

**elem.h**

```
__forceinline inline void MouseMove(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lp,RECT rr)
{
for (int i(0); i < col_count; i++)
    if (col[i])
            if (col[i]->Hover(LOWORD(lp), HIWORD(lp)) == 1 && !col[i]->bold)
            {
                col[i]->Bold();

                rr.left = col[i]->x;
                rr.top = col[i]->y;
                rr.right = col[i]->x + col[i]->cx + 1;
                rr.bottom = col[i]->y + col[i]->cy;

                InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rr, 0);
                UpdateWindow(hwnd);
            }
            else if (!col[i]->Hover(LOWORD(lp), HIWORD(lp)) && col[i]->bold)
            {
                col[i]->Bold();

                rr.left = col[i]->x;
                rr.top = col[i]->y;
                rr.right = col[i]->x + col[i]->cx + 1;
                rr.bottom = col[i]->y + col[i]->cy;

                InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rr, 0);
                UpdateWindow(hwnd);
            }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#inlcude"elem.h"
...//где-то в WndProc
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
MouseMove(hwnd,lp,rr);
break;
...
```

Comment: Проблемы производительности надо исследовать с помощью специальных инструментов, называемых *профилировщик*. Более правильным подходом, как мне кажется, будет замена гигантского массива указателей на более высокоуровневый контейнер (`std::map` или `std::unordered_map`). Таким образом цикл по 100000 элементам будет просто не нужен.

Comment: @alexolut , но почему же тогда проблем нет когда обработчик не является функцией? Может всё таки дело в `inline`, я как-то не так что-то понял? И разве в реализации в `std::map` не такой же алгоритм перебора?

Comment: В вопросе описывается "мистическое" поведение, которое скорее всего не имеет места в действительности. Вы либо что-то недоговариваете, либо что-то выдумываете. Простое вынесение кода в функцию не может и не будет иметь такого влияния не производительность.

Comment: @АртурКлочко я хочу сказать, что в map не придется хранить NULL элементы, то есть эффективный размер будет существенно меньше 100000, если в исходном массиве их много. Таким образом, количество итераций радикально уменьшится.

Comment: @AnT многократные лишние вызовы функции в цикле разве не дадут проседание производительности?

Comment: @alexolut: Нет, конечно. Накладные расходы, затрачиваемые именно на сам вызов такой тяжеленной функции, ничтожны, недетектируемо малы. А уж говорить о накладных расходах на вызов функции в контексте GUI-обработчика вообще смешно.

Answer (score 0):

Сомнителен сам принцип хранения - массив из 100000 указателей, которые еще и обрабатываются при `MOUSEMOVE`. Даже в этом варианте имеет смысл ненулевые собирать в начале, и прерывать цикл при обнаружении первого нулевого.

Если вы реально видите разницу между функцией и руками вставленным кодом - поработайте с профайлером, чтоб понять, где узкое место. Но самая большая оптимизация - это оптимизация алгоритмов и структур данных. Вот все же, сколько у вас реально ненулевых указателей в массиве? Может, тот же список был бы эффективнее?

И еще - ну зачем этот дубляж кода? Раз уж вы проверяете

```
col[i]->Hover(LOWORD(lp), HIWORD(lp)) == 1
```

то делаю вывод, что ваши флаги принимают значения 0 и 1 - а тогда проще сделать одну ветку как

```
if (col[i]->Hover(LOWORD(lp), HIWORD(lp)) + col[i]->bold == 1)
```

и не мучиться с дублированием кода.

Comment: Не нулевые и так в начале, это понятно. Ладно, буду искать решение с помощью профайлера этого. Спасибо!